# To search a file with first part of the file name in a share path and search for the file in Desktop, C , D drives using .Bat files

Tags: html, batch-file

Steps to be followed

1.I need to search for a file in a share path (Eg., auto)

1. If the file found - have to take the full name of the file (Eg., Auto restart.xlsm)

3.Then have to check for the file in Desktop, C , and D drives.

4.If the file not found - Paste the file in D drive

I have Html file to invoke these steps but .bat file only regognise the file in share path. So If it is possible to do in .bat script? Anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

```
    dir /S C:\auto*
    dir /S C:\auto*
```

this command will give you a list of files with "auto" on their names*(in C and E drives) i dunno about coping them :\ sry